# Winrt Phone 8.1 Application share task functionality on Page works only once

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have a page in my application which share simple text, not working properly.

Steps to produce this functionality.

1. Go to Page click share it shows application which can share.
2. Tap back button => click again on share button.
3. This will not open share screen this time.

Pasting my code below:

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        _dataTransferManager.DataRequested -= OnDataRequested;
        this.navigationHelper.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        _dataTransferManager = DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView();
        _dataTransferManager.DataRequested += OnDataRequested;
        this.navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }

    private void OnDataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Request.Data.Properties.Title =  obj.Title;
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(obj.Description);
        string html = "";
        foreach (HtmlNode item in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants())
        {
            if (item.Name == "body")
            {
                html = item.InnerHtml;
            }
        }
        e.Request.Data.Properties.Description = html;
        e.Request.Data.SetText(html);
    }

    private void AppBarButton_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI();
        if (CMSService.IsConnectedToInternet())
        {
            DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI();
        }
        else
        {
            ContentText.Text = App.GetResource("NoInternetAlert");
            AlertMessage.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
```

And while debugging share works all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the problem is because you unsubscribe from `_dataTransferManager.DataRequested -= OnDataRequested;` in *OnNavigatedFrom* event. This will work fine when debugging, hence this event won't be raised - while debuging PLM is disabled and [*Suspending/Resuming* events won't be raised](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24103101/2681948).

When running app normal, suspension will invoke *OnNavigatedFrom*, but [*OnNavigatedTo* won't be raised upon resuming](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29412402/2681948), thus there won't be susbscription to `_dataTransferManager.DataRequested += OnDataRequested;`.

In this case you probably can use *Suspending/Resuming* (or other) events to handle *DataTransferManager*.

Comment: I don't know how to register suspending/Resuming event on a single page

Comment: You are right, exactly same thing is happening now problem is that there is no event firing while resuming the application. If you tell me any event that fired on resuming it will be helpful

Comment: Or I can only unregister this datarequest event on navigating back

Comment: @Yawar Everything depends on what you need to achieve. Your app also should handle suspension properly.